# readystate 4 responsetext status 404 statustext not found

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint

I try to show my profile picture using the REST API but I get the error message (readystate 4 responsetext status 404 statustext not found)

here is my code:

```
window._spPageContextInfo = { crossDomainContextPhotosEnabled: true };
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        GetCurrentUser();

        function GetCurrentUser() {
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties?$select=PictureURL",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var userName = data.d.DisplayName;
                    var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
                    $('#bild').attr('src', picUrl);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I would be grateful if you could solve it

Comment: Try accessing the API endpoint via browser first to see if it's reachable.

Comment: Then it's more of a server-side issue that it's unable to consume your requests

Comment: what's your suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a SharePoint Hosted Add-in/App, in which case this would be a cross-domain call, which requires SP.RequestExecutor.js.

Also, you might want to try this code instead:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
context.load(userProfileProperties);
context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);
```

Then you can get your profile picture within your success callback function.

Comment: I have tested run code and got the link to the picture but it does not displayed. the picture is broken

Comment: May you elaborate on how the picture is broken?

Comment: just look at my answer

Comment: Try to open the image URL to see if it is actually bringing a permission error

Comment: Do you mean to open image URL in browser?   When I actually open the URL in a browser then the image will be displayed

Comment: There are way too many reasons why that might be happening, so I'll limit myself to answering the SharePoint question. Try to see if there's anything on the console, otherwise you'll be better off googling the image problem.